# Magic link in a new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, get

i have a magic link* to add an url to my website

```
javascript:document.location='http://domain.com/add.php?u='+escape(window.location);
```

is it possible to add the link in a new tab? like ...

```
javascript:window.open('http://domain.com/add.php?u='+escape(window.location));
// this code opens the magic link in a new tab but the current page shows [object Window]
```

*Simply copy the following magic link into your browser’s address bar. If you wish to post a url to domain.com, click this link, in the address bar, on the video’s page

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** This video describes it better what i mean
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h39NqC47Oag

Answer (score 1):

You may use this for open a new window-

```
function open_url(){
var URL = 'http://domain.com/add.php?u='+escape(window.location);
window.open(URL,"_blank","toolbar=yes, location=no, directories=no, status=no, 
    menubar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, copyhistory=no, width='624',height='566',
    left=20, top=50'");
}
```

I was not check but you may find some hints.

Comment: Same porblem: The current page is changing and shows [object window] 

javascript:window.open('http://domain.com/add.php?u='+escape(window.location),"_blank","toolbar=yes, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, copyhistory=no, width='624',height='566',    left=20, top=50'");

Comment: can u write here how u call that function `open_url()` in your html

Comment: check this page -> http://www.grabit.to/ (orange box: Magic Link) and you understand what i try to do  ;)

Answer (score 0):

In Google Chrome your booth links works OK for me. Then I tested in Firefox and I got `[object window]` in the original tab, but the link opened correctly in a new tab. I suppose that you are using IE (I can't test it, I'm on Linux) in which probably the second tab doesn't open.

The problem is that `window.open(...)` returns a `window` object, and the browser tries to "show" that object in screen (just as when you execute `alert(window)`).

**Solution**: you have to *collect* the window object, so the browser doesn't try to show it on screen:

```
javascript:var o = window.open('http://google.com?u='+escape(window.location));
```

(please, notice the `var o =` at the begining)